# Login with java smartcardio

Tags: java, smartcard

I need to login through smartcard.
The card is  an Italian healthcare card (TS) National Service Card (CNS).
I'm trying to compare the Common name with the Authentication certificate but I don't know how to do it. On the instructions provided I've found that:

> the certificate format is standard  ISO/9594-8 (X.509); the Common
>   name in the certificate must follow the structure ->
>   codicefiscale/idcarta.hash(ef_dati_personali) where codicefiscale is
>   tax code, idcarta is the Serial Number (16 ASCII characters of the
>   card) and ef_dati_personali is personal data. For
>   hash(ef_dati_personali) only useful characters must be used ('00'hex
>   at the end must be excluded).

I can obtain all this data separately with the code underlying but I cannot get the certificate.

```
 try {
                        // Display the list of terminals
                        TerminalFactory factory = TerminalFactory.getDefault();
                        List<CardTerminal> terminals = factory.terminals().list();
                    System.out.println("Terminals: " + terminals);

                    // Use the first terminal
                    CardTerminal terminal = terminals.get(0);

                    // Connect wit hthe card
                    Card card = terminal.connect("*");
                    System.out.println("card: " + card);
                    CardChannel channel = card.getBasicChannel();

                    //GET ATR
                    ATR atr = card.getATR();
                    byte[] ATR = atr.getBytes();
                    System.out.println("ATR della carta: " + bytesToHex(ATR));

                    //GET SELECT_FILE_APDU
                    byte[] dati_personali = {(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xA4, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x00};
                    byte[] c_carta = {(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xA4, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x00};
                    byte[] id_carta = {(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xA4, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x00};
                    byte[] inst_file = {(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xA4, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x12, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x41, (byte) 0x42, (byte) 0x00};
                    byte[] servizi_installati = {(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xA4, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x12, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x12, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x00};
                    byte[] gdo = {(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xA4, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x3F, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x2F, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x00};
                    byte[] key_pub = {(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xA4, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x3F, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x3F, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x00};

                    richiedi(channel, READ_BINARY_APDU, dati_personali, "<b>Dati personali:</b><br>");
                    richiedi(channel, READ_BINARY_APDU, c_carta, "<b>Carta:</b><br>");
                    richiedi(channel, READ_BINARY_APDU, id_carta, "<b>ID Carta:</b><br>");
                    richiedi(channel, READ_BINARY_APDU, inst_file, "<b>Inst File:</b><br>");
                    richiedi(channel, READ_BINARY_APDU, servizi_installati, "<b>Servizi installati:</b><br>");
                    richiedi(channel, READ_BINARY_APDU, gdo, "<b>GDO:</b><br>");
                    richiedi(channel, READ_BINARY_APDU, key_pub, "<b>KEY PUB:</b><br>");


                    // Disconnect the card
                    card.disconnect(false);
                    System.out.println("DISCONEESSO ");

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Ouch: " + e.toString());
                }
```

//

```
 public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bytes.length * 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02x", bytes[i]));
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
```

//

```
public void richiedi(CardChannel channel, byte[] read, byte[] select, String titolo) throws CardException {
        out.println(titolo);

        // Send Select Applet command
        ResponseAPDU answer = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(select));

        // Send test command
        answer = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(read));
        byte r[] = answer.getData();
        String test = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
            test += (char) r[i];

        }
        System.out.print(test);

        out.println(test);

        out.println("<br><br>");

    }
```

Comment: You should try to reduce the program a bit, and Italian identifiers may also be an obstacle. Apart from that: None of the files you list above looks like a certificate, to find the FID of the interesting certificate you should take a look at the CNS specification. Warning: not only is logging in with a smart card somewhat tricky on the OS integration side, there may also be legal restrictions on using an existing PIN for your two-factor authentication.

Comment: This post lacks a clear error description. Where does it fail and what data are you able to retrieve?